# I get a CORS Error for uploads above ~30mb, works for everything else

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, electron, gcloud

I am writing an electron app, The frontend breaks an upload into chunks and sends them to my backend. A separate project is running my backend (Express). When I point my express app to the local backend I get no CORS errors, as expected since the backend is running on the same origin at http://localhost:4000.

When I containerize the backend at push it to google cloud run, then point my frontend to that, I get a weird CORS issue, that I will detail here:

1. The Preflight request works fine and returns a 204 status code. [image: Preflight Status]
2. The subsequent Post request though is where it gets weird. When I upload a chunk that is less than about ~30mb It works fine, but any thing above even as close as 35mb, I get this: [image: Post request error]
   [image: Error header continuation]

This is how all my middleware was originally set up

```
const app = express();
const upload = multer();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.raw());
```

I have also tried:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: true,
  })
);
```

and even:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*"
  })
);
```

both of which didn't work.

Lastly, I tried disabling the cache from my electron devtools (see below) just in case it was a caching issue:
[image: Disabled cache]

Right now I have no clue what else could be causing this, I suspected Gcloud for a brief period, but it doesn't seem like there's any way to mess with Cors while configuring gcloud run.

Which leaves me a bit confused, is there some file limit for express uploads that I'm not aware of?